# Getting error saying that my program has crashed in C even though it show no issue with the syntax

Tags: c

I am confused as to why my program keeps on crashing. I am using [Code Blocks](http://codeblocks.org/), an open source IDE.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
  int age;
  char gender;

  printf("What is your age?\n");
  scanf(" %d", age);

  printf("What is your gender? \(m/f)\n");
  scanf(" %c", gender);

  if (age>=18){
    printf("Access granted! Please proceed\n");

    if (gender == 'm'){
      printf("What's up dude?");
    };
    if (gender == 'f'){
        printf("How's it going dudette?");
    };
  };
  if (age<18){
    printf("Access denied. Please get on with your life.\n");
  };

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %d", &age);`, `scanf(" %c", &gender);`

Comment: You don't need semicolons after your end-of-block `}` — they're mainly needed after enum, structure and union definitions, and initializers.  Additionally, if your compiler is not telling you what's wrong with your calls to `scanf()`, you either need to turn on (a lot) more warnings or you need to be using a better compiler.

Comment: Also notice that C is not a language where you can be sure that if your code compiles, it will run without crashing.  It is very easy to make code that compiles that will crash when run.  (It's also a good idea to end the dude's and dudette's messages with a newline.)  Except for the semicolon (null statement) before it, you could use `else` in place of `if (age < 18)`.

Comment: Please read more C books before asking beginners questions. You can choose a book from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: As a general note for `scanf`, be aware that taking input with `scanf` will often leave the `'\n'` in the input buffer (`stdin`) after the conversion is performed. While some conversion specifiers will ignore whitespace (including the `'\n'`), e.g.: `%d`, etc., others will not, e.g. `%s`. It is well worth the time to *read* `man scanf` thoroughly to understand the distinctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scanf requires a pointer to the variable you're setting.  So, you need to do:

```
scanf(" %d", &age);
```

and similar for gender